# Populate a drop down with jquery using another drop down

Tags: jquery, html, forms, jsp

I'm a beginner with jsp and jquery but I need your help to do something.

I am retrieving all entities University from my portlet and I'm populating with those a Select like this:

```
<%
List<University> us = UniversityLocalServiceUtil.getUniversitys(0, UniversityLocalServiceUtil.getUniversitysCount());
%>

 <div id="wrap">
<p>University</p>

<div>
    <label><span>Select an university:</span> <select
        name="unis" style="width: 259px">
            <option value="">-- SELECT --</option>
            <%
                for (University u : us) {
            %>
            <option value="<%=String.valueOf(u.getIdUniversity())%>">
                <%=u.getName()%>
            </option>
            <%
                }
            %>
    </select> </label>
</div>
```

then I have an hidden div which I want to reveal and populate with all the Faculties of the selected University.

```
 <div id="wraptwo">
 <p>Faculty</p>
    <div>
    <label><span>Select a Faculty:</span> <select
        name="facs" style="width: 259px">
            <option value="">-- SELECT --</option>
        <!-- TODO HERE -->  
    </select> </label>
</div>
```

I show it with the script:

```
<script>
$("#wraptwo").hide();
$('select[name="unis"]').change(function() {
    var uni = $(this).val();
    if (uni.length >= 1) {
        $("#wraptwo").show();

    } else {
        $("#wraptwo").hide();
    }
});
```

My problem now is that I need the value of the select called "unis" in order to retrieve all the faculties of the selected university with the method:

```
University u = UniversityLocalServiceUtil.getUniversity(primary_key_of_the_university);
List<Faculty> fs = u.getFacultys();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

`$( "select.unis option:selected").val();`

---

To pass the value back to the server, you could use an ajax call.  Something like this:

```
var uni = $( "select.unis option:selected").val();

$.ajax({
    url: '/your-url', // path to your url which gets this ajax request
    method: 'get', // or a http method you want to use
    data: {
        uni
    },
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

Syntax might be incorrect, but that's the gist of it.

Comment: Thanks, but how can i pass that value to the other Drop Down menu? or to a jsp variable?

Comment: JSP is server side, so you'll need to pass the value back to the server using an ajax call or a form submit.

Answer (score 0):

i think ur looking for this?

```
var uni = $(this).val();
$("<option></option").val(uni).text(uni).appendTo($("select.facs"))
```